# How do I hyperlink to a specific location in a VOB file?

Tags: video, windows-media-player

I rip various instructional DVDs that I own to my hard disk using AnyDVD on Windows 7. This process creates a bunch of VOB files that contain the chapter contents.

I can play the VOB files using Windows Media Player 12, but I really want to create a document that has a table of contents style list of various sections of various DVD chapters.

In other words, using Notepad, create a list of various subjects, each of which has links to multiple locations on different DVDs with content relevant to the subject. So I could open the file in a web browser, quickly scan the subjects and click on the links to the content I'm interested in.

This would save opening and closing the root or chapters of a DVD just to view a minute or two of content.

Thank you in advance for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to encode all or some of the chapters of the DVD you want to .MP4 or .M4V files and then use Media Player to play the chapters you desire.

Handbrake is fairly easy to use and allows to you select which chapters of the DVD to encode.